# Azure Data Factory Delta Load - Issues with Watermark

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to send the last update date to my control table. I follow the Msft guides for doing [incremental](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal) loads but get an error when calling the stored proc with the last update date.

I am able to insert values into the watermark column using a simple insert statement but it always fails when using the stored proc. The error message I get is:

```
SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM'.
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Admin.dbo.Data_Load_Params (
    Identifier varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    Source_Table varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    Target_Table varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    Table_Type varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    Last_Update_Column varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Schedule varchar(2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Watermark datetime NULL
) GO;
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_WriteWatermarkValue (@WatermarkValue datetime, @TableName varchar(50))
AS

BEGIN

    UPDATE Data_Load_Params 
    SET [Watermark] = @WatermarkValue 
WHERE [Target_Table] = @TableName

END
```

I then run:

```
exec USP_Write_Watermark('2020-12-09T17:16:15Z', 'Journal_Headers')
```

but have also used variations on the date like:

```
exec USP_Write_Watermark('1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM', 'Journal_Headers')
```

This issue is driving me bonkers as I have even copied the sample code from the Msft documentation.

Comment: Are you using Azure SQL?

Comment: Hi @Cobus van Rooyen, please correct me if I unstand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's syntax error when you execute a stored procedure not a problem with the date format. Why do you add a parenthesis? I mean you need to change `exec USP_Write_Watermark('2020-12-09T17:16:15Z', 'Journal_Headers')` to `exec USP_Write_Watermark '2020-12-09T17:16:15Z', 'Journal_Headers'`.

I've created a test to validate it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[person](
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LastModifytime] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[person]
 (PersonID, Name, LastModifytime)
 VALUES
 (1, 'aaaa','9/1/2017 12:56:00 AM'),
 (2, 'bbbb','9/2/2017 5:23:00 AM'),
 (3, 'cccc','9/3/2017 2:36:00 AM'),
 (4, 'dddd','9/4/2017 3:21:00 AM'),
 (5, 'eeee','9/5/2017 8:06:00 AM');

 select * from [dbo].[person];


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[watermarktable](
    [WatermarkValue] [datetime] NULL,
    [Target_Table] varchar(255)
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO watermarktable
VALUES ('1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM','dbo.person')

select * from [dbo].[watermarktable]

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_watermark] @WatermarkValue datetime, @TableName varchar(255)
        AS
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.watermarktable
            SET [WatermarkValue] = @WatermarkValue 
            WHERE [Target_Table] = @TableName

        END
GO


exec [dbo].[update_watermark] '2020-12-09T17:16:15Z', 'dbo.person'
exec [dbo].[update_watermark] '1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM', 'dbo.person'
```

It works well.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Joseph. The problem was the parenthesis. Thanks for all your efforts in testing your solution